# Cakephp 3.0 Class 'App\Controller\App' not found error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got this error when I tried to integrate Plugins for charts. The plugins I found online are all for cake version 2.*. I try to did the same for 3.0 and got this error.Here's my code.I also tried high charts and got the same thing.

```
use App\Controller\AppController;


App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('GoogleCharts', 'GoogleCharts.Lib');

class ChartsController extends AppController {

  public $helpers = array('GoogleCharts.GoogleCharts');

//Setup data for chart
  public function index() {
  $chart = new GoogleCharts();

  $chart->type("LineChart");  
    //Options array holds all options for Chart API
    $chart->options(array('title' => "Recent Scores")); 
    $chart->columns(array(
        //Each column key should correspond to a field in your data array
        'event_date' => array(
            //Tells the chart what type of data this is
            'type' => 'string',     
            //The chart label for this column           
            'label' => 'Date'
        ),
        'score' => array(
            'type' => 'number',
            'label' => 'Score',
            //Optional NumberFormat pattern
            'format' => '#,###'
        )
    ));

//You can also manually add rows: 
    $chart->addRow(array('event_date' => '1/1/2012', 'score' => 55));

//Set the chart for your view
    $this->set(compact('chart'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just throw Cake 2x and Cake 3x stuff together and expect it to work, in case the plugin is not made for 3.x, you simply cannot use it as such.

You are receiving the error because there is no `App` class in the current namespace, Cake 3x uses real namespaces and autoloading, so if you'd wanted to use the `App` class, you would have to import it using the `use` statement

```
use Cake\Core\App;
```

However there is no `App::uses()` anymore anyways, you either use autoloading, or simply [**include**](http://php.net/include_once)/[**require**](http://php.net/require_once) the files manually.

Suggested readings:

- **http://php.net/namespace**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html**
- **https://getcomposer.org/doc/**

Comment: @przemo_li Missing _what_?

Comment: proper using and namespace in code examples :D (esp. if somebody install from composer)

Comment: @przemo_li You mean like [here](http://goo.gl/UbZzsa), and [here](http://goo.gl/x6xUn0), and [here](http://goo.gl/wRfny5), and [here](http://goo.gl/CuCMkk), and [here](http://goo.gl/P2MYxt), and [here](http://goo.gl/dajmI9), and [here](http://goo.gl/o0hOmb), and [here](http://goo.gl/kp7Qbv), and... in case there are examples that are missing proper `use` statements and/or namespacing, just create an issue [over at GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/docs) so that it can be fixed in case necessary.

Comment: @przemo_li Namespacing and PSR-4 are PHP 101, if somebody doesn't know about that, then s/he maybe shouldn't use a fully fledged PHP framework like CakePHP, but instead start to learn the basics first - no offense though.